# Unable to execute protractor test from eclipse

Tags: protractor

example-spec.js:

```
 describe('Enter text in element on Protractor Example page', function() {

        it ('to check that text entered in text box displays on page',function() {
            browser.get('http://www.joecolantonio.com/ProtractorExample.html');
             element(by.model('joeAngularText')).sendKeys('Joe Colantonio');
             element(by.binding('joeAngularText')).getText().then(function(text){
             console.log(text);
             browser.pause();
            });
        });
    });
```

**Config file :**

```
    exports.config = {

        seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

        capabilities : {
            'browserName' : 'chrome'
        },

        specs : [ 'example_spec.js' ],

        jasmineNodeOpts : {
            onComplete : null,
            isVerbose : false,
            showColors : true,
            includeStackTrace : true
        }
    };
```

This is the error when i try to execute above script from eclipse 
node version: v6.10.1
protractor version 5.1.1

```
*D:\gdfgdf\Selenium\protractor\WS\Protractor\node_modules\protractor\built\logger.js:75
        info(...msgs) {
             ^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
        at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
        at require (module.js:385:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (D:\sdfds\Selenium\protractor\WS\Protractor\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:5:18)
        at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)*
```

Comment: can you add your `package.json` as well? Will be easier to see what is wrong.

Comment: The spec and the config look good, Protractor 5 should support the node 6.10. Check that you are really using Protractor 5.1 and node 6.10.

Comment: Just ran it from a terminal and inside eclipse and It seems to run fine for me. I think @alecxe is probably right. Make sure you are actually using the versions you think you are. http://imgur.com/a/MXcaN

Comment: Yes versions are correct only

Comment: am able run the script from command prompt but through eclipse its showing the error

Answer (score 0):

Replace the installed new version of the nodeJs file with the Eclipse NodeJs file. In windows go to the location where nodeJs installed `C:\eclipse-jee-neon-3-win32-x86_64(1)\eclipse\plugins\tern.eclipse.ide.server.nodejs.embed.win32.win32.x86_64_1.2.0.201606160856\node-v4.2.4-win32-x86_64` and replace it with the newest one